# Why compilation clears input when validation state is changed in Angular?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, validation

I'm trying to implement a solution which would allow to display a list of violations for the field which mouse is over in a form of a tooltip (if any). I'd like to use the data-tooltip-html-unsafe (the derivation of tooltip which displays html content correctly) for this. Of course I'd prefer to use a single directive like **tooltip-validated** which would apply all the necessary directives to such element (like data-tooltip-html-unsafe) along with any logic needed (such as translations and so on). I managed to achieve my goals with the following code but there's a bug which is extremely difficult to track.

Here's the directive:

```
'use strict';

angular.module('example.common.directives')
    .directive('tooltipValidated', ['$translate', '$timeout', '$compile', function ($translate, $timeout, $compile) {

        function parseMessage(prefix, errors) {
            // skipped some logic here
            return 'parsed message';
        }

        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            require: 'ngModel',
            replace: true,
            link: function($scope, $element, $attributes, $ctrl) {
                $attributes.$set('data-tooltip-html-unsafe', "{{errorMessage}}");
                $attributes.$set('tooltip-trigger', "{{{true: 'mouseenter', false: 'never'}[memberForm.secondaryContact.$invalid]}}");
                $scope.$watch(function() {
                    return $ctrl.$valid;
                }, function(newValue) {
                    if(newValue) {

                    } else if($ctrl.$dirty) {
                        var errorMap = $ctrl.$error;
                        var prefix = $attributes.errorPrefix;
                        var message = parseMessage(prefix, errorMap);
                        $timeout(function() {
                            $scope.errorMessage = message;
                        });

                    }
                });
                $timeout(function() {
                    $element.removeAttr("tooltip-validated");
                    $compile($element)($scope); // this is what seems to cause the bug
                });
            }
        }
    }]);
```

And here's how am I using it:

```
<input type="email"
                       name="secondaryContact"
                       ng-model="member.secondaryContact"
                       ng-disabled="!editable"
                       class="g-input-text g-float-left"
                       ng-class="inputClass"
                       required
                       tooltip-validated
                       error-prefix="MEMBER_FORM.SECONDARY_CONTACT"
                       maxlength="30"/>
```

**The problem is** when the validation state changes (in either direction that is from invalid to valid and valid to invalid) the input gets cleared. This does not happen if

```
$compile($element)($scope);
```

is removed but then the tooltip doesn't get rendered. Why this line is causing such issue and how to come around this? Am I doing something wrong?

My solution is based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19224028/add-directives-from-directive-in-angularjs) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19224028/add-directives-from-directive-in-angularjs)

Thanks!

Comment: I think your issue is similar to what is state here? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25578469/in-the-angularjs-dynamic-email-validation-element-when-i-fill-out-the-email-che/25578697#25578697

Comment: I don't provide any html to my directive so there's nothing to replace I believe, is it?